# django template language for loops

Tags: django, django-templates, jinja2

so i have an html code that is using template variables. For some reason it looks like after i iterate through a template variable, the list is empty? Is it that the pointer need to be reset to the index 0 of the template variable? thanks! The second select has nothing to iterate over and has no option values. Years is an array that  is like such [2015,2016,2017,2018]

```
<select data-placeholder="Choose Year 1..." id="yr1">
   {% for year in years %}
   <option value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
<h4 style="margin-bottom: 0px; margin-right: 20px; margin-left: 20px">to</h4>
<select data-placeholder="Choose Year 2..." id="yr2">
   {% for year in years %}
   <option value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Here is the view

```
def organization_reports(request):
 now = datetime.datetime.now()
 years = reversed(["{0}".format(year) for year in range(now.year-7,now.year)])
 my_dict = {"years" : years}
 return render(request, 'organization_reports/organization.html', my_dict)
```

Comment: This is probably because it is *not* a list, but a *generator*. Generators in Python pass *once* of the elements. But you need to show the view that generates the `years` to be sure.

Comment: the class type is <class 'list_reverseiterator'>

Comment: Then it is logical: `reversed(..)` is indeed a generator. You need to *materialize* it (for example by converting it to a `list(..)` to get it iterable multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reversed(..)` does *not* construct a collection of elements: it is an *iterator*, so that means that it iterates over something (well it yields elements), and if it is exhausted, there is no (direct) way to repeat the enumeration.

You thus need to *materialize* the iterator in some sort of collection, for example a `list`, or a `tuple`, for example:

```
def organization_reports(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    years = list(reversed(["{0}".format(year) for year in range(now.year-7,now.year)]))
    my_dict = {"years" : years}
    return render(request, 'organization_reports/organization.html', my_dict)
```

Or we can construct the `list` by *reversing* the `range(..)` object itself, that needs to be enumerated only once:

```
def organization_reports(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    years = ["{0}".format(year) for year in reversed(range(now.year-7,now.year))]
    my_dict = {"years" : years}
    return render(request, 'organization_reports/organization.html', my_dict)
```

or we can even encode the reversal in the `range(..)` object itself:

```
def organization_reports(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    years = ["{0}".format(year) for year in range(now.year-1,now.year-8, -1)]
    my_dict = {"years" : years}
    return render(request, 'organization_reports/organization.html', my_dict)
```

Regardless how we construct it, the result is that `years` is now a *collection*, not an *iterator*. One can (normally) enumerate a collection an arbitrary number of times (and this definitely holds for `list`s and `tuple`s).